# Correct Syntax for Const Reference

Tags: c++

Is here a difference between `Box operator + (const Box& box2){"overload code"}` and `Box operator +(Box const& box2){"overload code"}` if you have a custom class called Box? And if so, what is the difference?

Comment: No they're exactly the same.

Comment: No, there's no difference.

Comment: `const Box&` could be read as "a reference to a `Box` that is constant", and `Box const&` could be read as "reference to a constant `Box`. Semantically exactly the same.

Comment: What if it was (Box const &box2)  or (const Box &box2), is there any difference? between it and the  first two? @john

Comment: Spaces are irrelevant here. You can have `const Box& box1`, `const Box &box1`, `const    Box    &    box1`, or even add newlines or tabs instead of spaces. Any decent book, tutorial or class should have taught you that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude unfortunately my begineers class professor wasn't the type to explain basics like that without someone asking a question.

Comment: @edo101 No worries. Bad teachers can't stop our thirst for knowledge. Go ahead and see [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/10147399). Pick up something for beginners and you'll be golden. I recommend [C++ Primer](https://www.amazon.com/Primer-5th-Stanley-B-Lippman/dp/0321714113), it's really well written.

Comment: @Ayxan thanks for the suggestion. Yeah for me I am learning way more outside of class as I youtube video tutorials and try to follow

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Those two are identical. `int const&i`, `int const& i`, `int const &i`, `int const & i`, `const int&i`, `const int &i`, `const int& i`, `const int & i` all have the exact same type: reference to a constant `int`.

Comment: What if it was (Box const &box2)  or (const Box &box2), is there any difference? between it and the  first two @Ayxan

Comment: No, no difference.

Comment: so (Box const &box2) and (Box const& box2) are the same thing which are the same as (const Box& box2) and (const Box &box2)? @Ayxan

Comment: Yes, exactly. The placement of `const` before or after the type, or the existence of white space before or after `&` does not change anything whatsoever.

Comment: thank you @Ayxan. How would you read it out loud? "referene to a constant box? "

Comment: Yes, exactly. You could also say "reference to a const box" or a "const box reference" and everyone will still understand.